# jquery fullcalendar eventclick not working in week / day view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

the select event works properly, but the eventClick is not working for these views (agendaWeek / agendaDay) although it works fine in the month view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventClick: function (calEvent, start) {                               
            $("#btnRemove").show();
            $dlg.editdialog("open", { start: calEvent.start, end: calEvent.end, labId: $("#ddlLab").val(), id: calEvent.id });

            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        },

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        disableDragging: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {

            $("#btnRemove").hide();
            $dlg.editdialog("open", { start: start, end: end, labId: $("#ddlLab").val() });

        },
        editable: true
    });
```

I solved the problem by using (disableResizing:true)

Comment: you forget something, code maybe?!

Comment: Please clarify what “is not working” means.

Comment: the dialog "dlg" opens when i click an event in the month view, but it dosen't open in the week / day agenda views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using (disableResizing:true)